# Formula to convert hours to days

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion

```
name    day1 day2  day3   day4 day5  totalhr  DAY 
person1 2hr  4hr   1.5hr  1hr  2hr   11.5 
Person2 3hr  2.4hr 2hr    2hr  3hr   12.5 
Person3 3hr  2hr   2hr    2hr  3hr   12hr
```

I have an Excel sheet that has text values (like the examples above).

I want a way I can convert them into days such that:

If I have 12hrs, it rounds off to the nearest day and becomes 1 Day.
If it is more than 12 hrs, it can say for example 1 day 2 hrs. Until the 2hrs grows to 12hrs it becomes 1 day.

It is important to note that the values are in **General format** and not date or time.

> **I see the hours is making it so difficult.**
>
> Can we ignore the hrs from both the input value: it should be total 12
>    = 1day 3hr (where 3 is the hours or without hr).

I don't want to convert to strings. If the formula is **without hrs it is fine.** My point is how to had i.e. 2 , 3 , 1, each representing hours when it gets to a total of 12, it becomes one day. 12 hours = 1 day. you can ignore hrs in the formula.

Thanks

Comment: 1 day = 24 hours, not 12 hours.

Comment: What is your question? How to extract numeric values from strings that contain numbers (e.g., how to extract 1.5 from ```1.5hr```), or how to do the rounding? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Simple I want a formula that adds total numbers of different days and calculate if it is = 12 hours, then it  = 1 day. If more than 12 hours i.e 13hours = 1 day 1hour, if = 24hours, then it is = 2 days. etc. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=IF(MOD(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr",""),24)>=12,ROUND(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr","")/24, 0), FLOOR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr","")/24,1)&" D "&MOD(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr",""),24)&" H")
```

Where `E5`is your cell for example.

Explanation:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr","")
```

removes "hrs" and "hr".

Then other part checks if the `MOD` of hours is >= 12:

- When Yes, then round it to the next day
- When No, then write down the `FLOOR`, followed by the hours

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. This worked. Here is the formular I used: 
 `=IF(MOD(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr",""),12)>=12,ROUND(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr","")/12, 0), FLOOR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr","")/12,1)&" D "&MOD(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"hrs",""),"hr",""),12)&" H") `


I only changed 24 to 12 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @annjenny Great, then please accept the answer

Comment: I gave it upvote already. Just let me know how I can accept it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done. I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the numbers from the cell with time (if the time is in cell A2):

```
=LEFT(A2,SUM(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},""))))
```

You can add the value of several cells by having this formula in a `SUM()`function, one for each cell.

Say that you put that in `E5`you can then convert it to days and hours with something like :

```
= QUOTIENT(E5,24) & IF(E5/24<2, " Day ", " Days ") & MOD(E5,24) & IF(MOD(E5,24)<2, " Hour", " Hours")
```

And round up anything less than a day by putting that in an if like:

```
= IF(E5/24<1, "1 Day",QUOTIENT(E5,24) & IF(E5/24<2, " Day ", " Days ") & REST(E5,24) & IF(REST(E5,24)<2, " Hour", " Hours"))
```

Sources: 
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/11/22/excel-extract-number-from-string/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that Data in Range `A2:F4`.
- Array (CSE) Formula in `G2`:

`{=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(A2:F2,"hr",""))&"hr"}`

**N.B.** Finish Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

- Enter this Formula in `H2` & fill it down.

  ```
  =INT(INT(SUBSTITUTE(G2,"hr","")/24)) & " days" & " "&INT(MOD(SUBSTITUTE(G2,"hr",""),24)) & " hours"
  ```

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*